# my if statement doesn't work when checking radio input

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, radio-button

Im trying to validate radio input to check if its correct answer.
But it skips the line `if (answer == allQuestions[q].correctAnswer)`

here is whole code https://jsfiddle.net/alcatel/sopfmevh/1/

```js
for (let k = 0; k < answers.length; k++) {
  if (answers[k].checked) {
    answer = answers[k].value;
  }
}

// IT SKIPS THIS LINE !!
if (answer == allQuestions[q].correctAnswer) { // IT SKIPS THIS LINE!!
  alert("correct");
}

q++;
    
populate();
```

Comment: Please paste your whole code in the question. Avoid links.

Comment: And I actually don't see any elements in your HTML named 'answers'

Comment: radio.setAttribute("name", "answers");

Comment: Simple debugging will tell you why..... `console.log(answer, allQuestions[q].correctAnswer, answer == allQuestions[q].correctAnswer);`

Comment: this is typically the use case of a generator function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your If statement should look like this instead

```
if(answer == allQuestions[q].choices[allQuestions[q].correctAnswer]) {
        alert("correct");
    }
```

Editied this, just tried and works for me

Comment: well your original IF statement `allQuestions[q].correctAnswer` just gives you the index of the correct answer, as that is what you have stored in in your object array, so you need to use that index and put it back into the same array, so if `correctAnswerIndex = allQuestions[q].correctAnswer` then `allQuestions[q][correctAnswerIndex]` will give you the right answer

Comment: I think a better way of storing your data would just be to replace `correctAnswer: 1` with `correctAnswer: Finland` that way you can just do what you had originally

Comment: Ben - you are answering Matias' question "Why didn't my code work?" in a comment — the _why_ should be part of your _answer_... Here's what you did, here's why that doesn't work, here's how to do it correctly, code example solving OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also compare by using the index of the element in the array.

```
if(allQuestions[q].choices.indexOf(answer) == allQuestions[q].correctAnswer) {
    alert("correct");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because I did it...

```js
const allQuestions = 
        [ { question     : 'Where is Helsinki?'
          , choices      : [ 'Sweden', 'Finland', 'Us' ] 
          , correctAnswer: 1
          } 
        , { question     : 'Where is Stockholm?'
          , choices      : [ 'Norway', 'Iceland', 'Sweden' ] 
          , correctAnswer: 2
          } 
        , { question     : 'Where is Köpenhamn?'
          , choices      : [ 'Denmark', 'Sweden', 'Norway' ] 
          , correctAnswer: 0
          } 
        ] 
function* qList(arr) { for (let q of arr) yield q }

const libQuestion  = document.querySelector('h1')
  ,   formReplies  = document.getElementById('list')
  ,   btNext       = document.querySelector('button')
  ,   DomParser    = new DOMParser()
  ,   qListRead    = qList( allQuestions )
  ,   score        = { correct: 0, count:0 }
  ;
var currentAnswer = ''
  ;
function setNewQuestion()
  {
  formReplies.innerHTML = ''

  let newQuestion = qListRead.next()
  if (!newQuestion.done)
    {
    libQuestion.textContent = newQuestion.value.question
    currentAnswer           = newQuestion.value.correctAnswer
    ++score.count
    newQuestion.value.choices.forEach((choice,indx)=>
      {
      let line = `<label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="${indx}">${ choice}</label>`
        , inLn = (DomParser.parseFromString( line, 'text/html')).body.firstChild
        ;
      formReplies.appendChild(inLn)
      })
    }
  else
    {
    libQuestion.textContent = ` Score = ${score.correct} / ${score.count}`
    btNext.disabled         = true
    }
  }
setNewQuestion()
btNext.onclick=()=>
  {
  if (formReplies.answer.value)
    {
    score.correct += ( currentAnswer == formReplies.answer.value )
    setNewQuestion()
    }
  }
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<p></p>
<form id="list"></form>
<br>
<button>next</button>
```